how to autogenerate context for APIView methods
I need to write my own APIView class which overrides drf's APIView and it will have autogenerated self.context which I can pass into serializer.
For example
class SomeView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        ser = SomeSerializer(data=request.data, context = self.context)
        ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(ser.validated_data)


Why not use the GenericAPIView which does that already?

Why not use the GenericAPIView [drf-doc] which does that already?
Indeed, we can work with:
class SomeView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        ser = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(ser.validated_data)
This will use the get_serializer_context() method, by default this will pass the request, format, and view to the context, but you can add extra context data like:
class SomeView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        ser = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(ser.validated_data)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {**super().get_serializer_context(), 'foo': 42}
This will thus add an extra foo item as context.

Ohh, thanks, this is exacly what i needed, but i just didn't know that its already realized in GenericAPIView.
Thanks a lot
